# How can I filter a list of strings, creating a list containing only those meeting my criteria?

Tags: c#, string, list

In my application I want the program to search through a list, testing each list element. If the list element is the required length I then want this to be inserted into a new list. Below is the code I have already

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>();
List<string> newFoo = new List<string>();

for (int h = 0; h < l; h++);
{
    // Here I want to search through every element of foo and if the element
    // length is greater than say 5 i want to add it to the newFoo 
}
```

I don't know how to search through each element and any examples I can find use LINQ which I don't want to do as I'm sure there is a simpler way. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried to achieve it?

Comment: LINQ is the simplest way, don't know why you think it's not.

Comment: Oh why would you want to do this?  can you explain your problem more - it's likely another data structure is appropriate

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek not for someone that doesn't know how to use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: LINQ: `var newFoo = foo.Where(x => x.Length > 5).ToList();` - It won't get any simpler than this.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Well, it won't get a lot *shorter* than that. But I think for a newcomer to C#, a simple foreach loop is *simpler* to understand. It's all a matter of perspective.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I really meant *simpler*. I would say that you don't even need programming experience to understand that this code filters `foo`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I'm really not so sure about that. Or at least, you may be able to read it but have very little clue as to how to modify it to something *similar* but not quite the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [`foreach` loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

```
foreach (string element in foo)
{
    if (element.Length > 5)
    {
        newFoo.Add(element);
    }
}
```

However, assuming you start with an empty `newFoo` list, this is better done with LINQ:

```
List<string> newFoo = foo.Where(x => x.Length > 5).ToList();
```

Or if you already have an existing list, you can use:

```
newFoo.AddRange(foo.Where(x => x.Length > 5));
```

(In my experience it's more common to be creating a new list, mind you.)

If you're new to C#, you should probably make sure you understand the first form before you move on to use LINQ, lambda expressions etc.

Note that if you really, really want to use a straight `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop, you can do so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Count; i++)
{
    string element = foo[i];
    if (element.Length > 5)
    {
        newFoo.Add(element);
    }
}
```

... but I'd strongly recommend using `foreach` any time you want to iterate over a sequence and don't really care about the index of each entry.

Comment: Even **without** one, there's still `AddRange`.

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Indeed. Will add that.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks I added in your Linq version but the result i get isnt the data it seems to be the function to get the data   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @user2546071: You're probably just printing out `newFoo.ToString()` - that won't list the elements...

Comment: after the insert I'm printing the data using tablefill                  //Refreshs the Client table on display from the 
                     this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.CalcDataSet.Client);
 not sure if that similar or not ?

Comment: @user2546071: We have no idea what *any* of those parts are, or how they relate to your list.

Comment: ah I thought the table adapter would effect it ...will theres nowhere actually printing except for the sqlcommands which are doing n insert so I can't actually see anywhere were newFoo.toString() may be occuring

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like this (foreach loop):

```
  foreach (String item in foo)
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, item)) // <- be careful with nulls!
      if (item.Length > 5)
        newFoo.Add(item);
```

Or if you prefer index based access

```
  for (int i = 0; i < foo.Count; ++i)
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, foo[i])) // <- be careful with nulls!
      if (foo[i].Length > 5)
        newFoo.Add(foo[i]);
```

Yet another possibility is LINQ, e.g.

```
  // Do not forget the nulls... 
  newFoo.AddRange(foo.Where(item => Object.ReferenceEquals(null, item) ? false : item.Length > 5));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to filter items with `Length > 5` to your `newFoo` List

```
List<string> newFoo = foo.Where(r => r.Length > 5).ToList();
```

If you want to use simple `for` loop then:

```
for (int h = 0; h < foo.Count; h++) 
{
    if (foo[h] != null && foo[h].Length > 5)
        newFoo.Add(foo[h]);
}
```

*(Remember to remove the `;` semicolon at the end of your for-loop, currently it will not do anything since it will consider `;` as the only statement for the loop to work on)*

Answer (score 2):

Without Linq, you can do it with a simple loop

```
foreach(var f in foo)
{
    if(f.Length > 5)
    {
        newFoo.Add(f); 
    }
}
```

But with Linq, it's even simpler

```
newFoo = foo.Where(f => f.Length > 5).ToList()
```